# How to save Date and Time state of Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datetimepicker, onsaveinstancestate

I have two EditText. First, use to open DatePicker, and the second use to open TimePicker.
I have created DialogFragment for two-component. Both works.All in the Fragment.

This is my Fragment. When select DatePicker the value of Time disappears and When I select TimePicker Date also disappear. I have already saveInstance. Pls, help!! Thx

```
DialogFragment datePicker;
TimePickerFragment timePicker;

EditText departureEdt;
EditText departureTimeEdt;
String selectedDate;
String selectedTime;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (outState != null) {
        outState.putString("selectedDate", selectedDate);
        outState.putString("selectedTime", selectedTime);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        selectedDate = savedInstanceState.getString("selectedDate");
        selectedTime = savedInstanceState.getString("selectedTime");

        departureEdt.setText(selectedDate);
        departureTimeEdt.setText(selectedTime);

    }
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transportation_fragment, container, false);

    departureEdt = view.findViewById(R.id.departure_date);
    departureEdt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.setTargetFragment(TransportationFragment.this, 1);
            datePicker.show(fm, "datePicker");

        }
    });


    departureTimeEdt = view.findViewById(R.id.departure_time);
    departureTimeEdt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
            timePicker.setTargetFragment(TransportationFragment.this, 1);
            timePicker.show(fm, "timePicker");


        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // get date from string
        selectedDate = data.getStringExtra("selectedDate");
        selectedTime = data.getStringExtra("selectedTime");
        // set the value of the editText
        departureEdt.setText(selectedDate);
        departureTimeEdt.setText(selectedTime);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just don't set both at the same time. The time string will be null when the date is confirmed, and vice versa, which perfectly explains why one makes the other disappear. That's what request codes are made for, differentiating.

Comment: how can I solve it? Can you please suggest?

Comment: Use different request codes (they are both 1 currently, look at your `show` calls) and check the codes received in `onActivityCreated`, updating either the time or the date depending on which code was received.